# Multiple modules loading error

Tags: angularjs

I have several modules in my application, every module definition in separated js file:

```
angular.module('app', ['app.module1']);

angular.module('app.module1', ['app.module1.module2']);

angular.module('app.module1.module2', []);
```

And then I want to create controller for last module:

```
angular.module('app.module1.module2').controller('myController', function(){});
```

In this case I have error

```
Module 'app.module1.module2' is not available! You either misspelled the module name or forgot to load it. If registering a module ensure that you specify the dependencies as the second argument.
```

Could anyoune explain where is the problem? Sorry for newbie question.
**Note:** every definition in it's own js file.

Comment: Where are you creating the controller on app.module1.module2? Is it in a different file than where you're creating the app.module.module2 module? If it's in a different file the module declaration file needs to load first.

Comment: Works here: http://plnkr.co/edit/L310PHMhewEZMakGKBGv?p=preview You must be trying to create the controller before all modules have loaded as per @theJoeBiz

Comment: @theJoeBiz, yes, they are different files. But I thought that module loading happends only after angular bootstrapping

Comment: Thanks for your points, guys, I'll try to fix loading order

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cant use a module before it is created, so you must be carefull in which order you load then ,load the module definition first then you can reopen the module in a file loaded after the module definition file.

However it makes more sense to stick to one one module per file. That way you dont have to care in which order your module are declared.

so you could write thing instead :

```
angular.module('app.module1.module2.controllers',[])
.controller('myController', function(){});
```

then

```
angular.module('app.module1.module2', ['app.module1.module2.controllers']);
```

even if you load `app.module1.module2` after `app.module1.module2.controllers` it will work.

Comment: so do you offer to define module in one file? I have multiple modules with multiple dependencies, so I have to keep in mind testing and scaling.

Comment: yes defines one module per file OR keep track of the order in which modules are defined.Testing is not an issue.You can still mock dependencies.

Comment: I think that defining of module per file will be more scalable, so I'm going to fix order, thanks